# Test code coverage reduced to 0%

Tags: unit-test

I have some very unusual things happening with my test code coverage in Production. The coverage for *all* of my classes has suddenly been reduced to 0%. How does this happen ? Would this happen if somebody is making changes directly into Production ?

One other thing : I ran the test on one of the classes which was at 0%. The test failed, but the code coverage increased to 88%. How can that be ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The test coverage isn't maintained permanently. To regenerate your test coverage, just run all of your tests (although it is important to know that this value changes depending on if you are running it in Eclipse, etc for some reason).

As for why you can be at 88% coverage while you had a test failing, as long as part of your test ran you will get the coverage needed for the classes that had their code run.

To get a good idea of your code coverage, do the following:

[image: ApexClasses]

1. Clear Code Coverage (in red)
2. Compile all casses (in blue)
3. Run All Tests (in green)
4. Estimate your organization's code coverage (in orange)

Comment: Thank you Jesse. I didn't know test coverage wasn't permanent. I figured the only thing that reset it would be programming changes to the Prod such as new validation rules etc. Also - if that same class which failed testing (but then showed 88% coverage) were to fail during a deployment of new code to Prod (when all the tests are run) would it prevent the deployment to happen, or would it allow the deployment to work since it would still have 88% coverage ? Thanks again Jesse.

Comment: Yes it would definitely prevent the deploy. All unit tests must pass to deploy to production before code coverage is even taken into account.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of - thanks Jesse. I have a crazy problem with this classes because sometimes it passes and sometimes it doesn't. I've gone through it w/ debug but couldn't find the problem. It's pretty extensive code that scans records and sends out notices to Owners of recorsd which meet a certain criteria. Very weird problem.

Comment: @JesseAltman Thanks for posting this, I was stumped until I saw this.